# Import from execution path

Tags: python, python-2.7, type-hinting, mypy

I have a setup like this:

```
projectpath/__main__.py
projectpath/backend/__init__.py
projectpath/backend/backend1.py
projectpath/backend/backend2.py
```

The `__main__.py` imports and uses both backend files and `backend2.py` also imports and uses `backend1.py`. I used to do it like so:

`__main__.py:`

```
import backend.backend1 
import backend.backend2
```

`backend2.py:`

```
import backend1
```

And that worked, but now I am using mypy (Python static type checker), and that one requires all import paths to be relative to the `__main__.py`, so my backend2.py now looks like this:

```
import backend.backend1 as backend1
```

mypy now says this is fine, but when I try to execute it, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...]
  File "./backend/backend2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import backend.backend1 as backend1
```

Is there any way to allow imports in that style, so allowing imports from the execution path of `__main__.py`?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some example code to test this problem on a linux Debian 8.6 with python 2.7.9.
I can run both `mypy` tests and code on Python 2 interpreter importing modules this way:

> `projectpath/__main__.py`

```
from backend import backend2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ba2 = backend2.Backend2("ex")
    print ba2.getb1()
```

> `projectpath/backend/backend1.py`

```
class Backend1:
    def __init__(self, b=0):
        # type: (int) -> None
        self.b = b

    def b1(self):
        # type: () -> str
        return 'b1!'
```

> `projectpath/backend/backend2.py`

```
from backend1 import Backend1


class Backend2:
    def __init__(self, b='text'):
        # type: (str) -> None
        self.b = b

    def getb1(self):
        # type: () -> str
        x = Backend1()
        return 'b2:' + x.b1() + ';'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    z = Backend2()
    print z.getb1()
```

You can find [here](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python2.html) documentation about `mypy` type checking in Python 2.

Comment: So the problem doesn't exist anymore, right? I think remember reading that the `mypy` folks might have changed smth. in that regard.

Comment: I think it's possible.